# SQL Query - get row exites some value on other table laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query

```
$cartable = DB::table('requests')
        ->select('requests.*','crequest.*')
        ->leftJoin('crequest','crequest.id','=','requests.request_id')
        ->whereRaw("FIND_IN_SET('$userid', crequest.user_allows)")
        ->orderBy('forms_cartable.id','desc')->get();
```

my tables:

```
requests:
+------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| id   | request_name | request_priority | request_status    |
+------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1   |    test1    |         low       |      process      |
|  2   |    test2    |         low       |      process      |
|  3   |    test3    |         low       |      process      |
+------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+


crequest
+------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
| id   | request_id  | users_allow    | c_status     |
+------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
|  3   |    1        |  12,13,15      | done         |
|  4   |    1        |  12            | done         |
|  5   |    1        |  13            | end          |
|  6   |    2        |  42,12,35      | done         |
|  7   |    2        |  47,65         | done         |
|  8   |    3        |  42            | open         |
+------+-------------+----------------+--------------+
```

I want if there was an existing current user ID(Logged
) in crequest.user_allows return request`s only without crequest detail

look like this:

(if current user id 12 )
request table result (after execute query)

```
+------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| id   | request_name | request_priority | request_status    |
+------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1   |    test1     |         low      |      process      |
|  2   |    test2     |         low      |      process      |
+------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

but query result all record match in table crequest i need only requests rows if  have match in crequest table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `php` but you can achieve it in MySql in so many ways. These are 3 ways among them..

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT DISINCT R.*
FROM requests R
INNER JOIN crequest CR ON R.id = CR.request_id
WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('12', CR.users_allow);
```

**Method 2:**

```
SELECT *
FROM requests R
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM crequest CR WHERE R.id = CR.request_id 
AND FIND_IN_SET ('12', CR.users_allow));
```

**Method 3:**

```
SELECT *
FROM requests R
WHERE R.id in (SELECT request_id FROM crequest WHERE FIND_IN_SET ('12', CR.users_allow))
```